# How to call a function from another class?

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a function in another class. I need to use the surface area function or the information that was stored in it from the previous class for another class. How would I go about that?

I have already tried `HalfOpenCylinder::surfaceArea()` and `HalfOpenCylinder.surfaceArea()` and neither worked.

```
//surface area function that I want to use for other class
double HalfOpenCylinder::surfaceArea(double height, double pi) {

    double surfaceArea = (2 * pi * radius * height) + (pi * pow(radius, 2));
    return surfaceArea;
}
```

Comment: `HalfOpenCylinder h; h.surfaceArea(...);` - You need an instance of the class, and the function must be public unless the classes are related by inheritance.

Comment: Or `friend`s...

Comment: It sounds like the function should not be part of a class to be honest if you want to call it without having an object of that class to hand.

Comment: Why don't you post the code that wants to call the function to give us some context?

Comment: This does not answer your question. But you should always keep in mind that c++ supports free functions. And a utility function like calculating the surface areas, should rather a free function then a member function. And then it could be used independently from the class.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function from another class you need to first **create an object** (instance) of that class.
**Using that object you can call a particular function**

eg:

```
 #include <iostream> 
 using namespace std;  
    class Student 
    {         // defining class 
       public:  
          int id;

          void add(){
            int x=1;
            int y=2;
            int z=x+y;
            cout<<z<<endl;
            }


    };  
    int main() {  
        Student s1;      // creating object of  class

        s1.id=20;
        s1.add()                // calling function of that class


        return 0;  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written a script that shows you how you can

> "call a function in another class"

and

> "use the surface area function or the information that was stored in it from the previous class for another class".

This is a script with many examples in it. It uses an updated version of your surfaceArea() method (method being the term since the function is defined from within a class).  I have also included what output the script produces at the very bottom of the script.

You can copy and past this entire code segment into a C++ compiler and it should work for you.  I compiled and tested it in Visual Studio 2015 Community.  I went to new project, and created a "Win32 Console Application" in the C++ category.

```
// ConsoleApplication10.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
// This class example was created to answer kittykoder's question on StackOverflow.


// Both of these need to be included
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

// We need the std namespace
using namespace std;

// Here I am defining a struct so that you can easily take all the values out of the
// HalfOpenCylinder class at once, and even make a new Cylinder object with the values by
// using the struct in one of the two HalfOpenCylinder class constructors.
struct CylinderValues
{
public:
    CylinderValues(double radius, double height, double surfaceArea) {
        this->radius = radius;
        this->height = height;
        this->surfaceArea = surfaceArea;
    }
    __readonly double radius;
    __readonly double height;
    __readonly double surfaceArea;
};

// This is the class I saw in your example.  Since it is named 
// HalfOpenCylinder, I decided to treat it like an
// instantiatable object class, both because it makes sense name wise, 
// and based on the context you provided in your question.
class HalfOpenCylinder
{
public:
    // Pi is always 3.14, so there is no reason to make it a passable parameter
    // like in your example. Thus I have made it a constant.  It's a static constant because
    // of the static function I've placed in this class to help in answering your question.
    static const float pi;

    // I have encapsulated the variables that make up this
    // class's objects behind methods so that the surface area can be
    // updated every time the radius or height values are changed.
    double GetRadius() { return radius; }
    void SetRadius(double value) { radius = value; UpdateSurfaceArea(); }
    double GetHeight() { return height; }
    void SetHeight(double value) { height = value; UpdateSurfaceArea(); }
    double GetSurfaceArea() { return surfaceArea; }

    // You can make a HalfOpenCylinder object with this constructor
    HalfOpenCylinder(double radius, double height) {
        this->radius = radius;
        this->height = height;
        UpdateSurfaceArea();
    }

    // You can use another HalfOpenCylinder object to make a new HalfOpenCylinder object using
    // this constructor.
    HalfOpenCylinder(CylinderValues values) {
        radius = values.radius;
        height = values.height;
        surfaceArea = values.surfaceArea;
    }

    // This will return the struct needed to use the constructor just above this comment.
    CylinderValues CopyValues() {
        return CylinderValues(radius, height, surfaceArea);
    }

    // Here is your surface area calculation from your question
    static double CalculateSurfaceArea(double radius, double height) {
        return (2 * pi * radius * height) + (pi * pow(radius, 2));
    }

private:
    // Here are the values you wanted to be able to access from another class.
    // You can access them using the methods above for getting and setting. The 
    // surfaceArea value is automatically recalculated if you change either the
    // radius or height variable's values.
    double radius;
    double height;
    double surfaceArea;

    // This method is here so that HalfOpenCylinder objects can use the
    // Surface area calculation.  I could have copied and pasted the calculation
    // code here to avoid calling the static method, but then I would be writing code
    // more than need be.  This way, you can update one and the other will be correct.
    void UpdateSurfaceArea() {
        surfaceArea = CalculateSurfaceArea(radius, height);
    }
};

// This is honestly just here because the compiler yelled at me for defining a static
// constant inside a non-static class.  Could'a gotten away with it in C#.  Thank you compiler.
const float HalfOpenCylinder::pi = 3.141592;

// This is called a function since it is outside of any class (although,
// that is one of the few differences between functions and methods.
// Methods being, functions defined inside classes)
void ThisIsAFunction() {
    cout << "This is the text from the function named: ThisIsAFunction";
}

// This class is just here to show you how to call functions and methods from inside classes
class CallFunctionAndMethodTester
{
public:

    void MethodInsideTheClass() {
        cout << "The below is printed from a function called in a class: \n";
        // Here, I am calling a function from inside a class
        ThisIsAFunction();
        cout << "\n\nThe below is printed from a static method called in a class: \n";
        // Here, I am calling a static method from inside a class
        cout << HalfOpenCylinder::CalculateSurfaceArea(14.5, 50.5);

        // Here, I am making an object instance from inside a class
        HalfOpenCylinder bobTheCylinder(1.5, 5.4);
        cout << "\n\nThe below is printed from an object's method called in a class: \n";
        // Here, I am calling an object's method from inside a class
        cout << bobTheCylinder.GetRadius();
    }

};

// Ok.  We made it.  THIS main function is where we will use and
// test the classes we have made above.
int main() {

    // Make a new cylinder object.  No pointer, so it will be destroyed when the computer
    // reads past main (which is the end of this program anyways).
    cout << "Cylinder 1 Values: \n";
    HalfOpenCylinder cylinder1(5.0, 10.0); 
    cout << cylinder1.GetRadius();
    cout << "\n"; // <--just makin' a newline here
    cout << cylinder1.GetHeight();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << cylinder1.GetSurfaceArea();
    cout << "\n\n"; // <--just makin' two newlines here

    // Change the object's height.  The surface area updates automatically.
    cout << "Cylinder 1 new surface area once Height is changed: \n";
    cylinder1.SetHeight(20.5);
    cout << cylinder1.GetSurfaceArea();
    cout << "\n\n";

    // Make a second Cylinder using the first cylinder's values.
    cout << "Cylinder 2 Values: \n";
    HalfOpenCylinder cylinder2(cylinder1.CopyValues());
    cout << cylinder2.GetRadius();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << cylinder2.GetHeight();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << cylinder2.GetSurfaceArea();
    cout << "\n\n";

    // Here I'm using the static CalculateSurfaceArea function to use the surface area
    // method without having to make a new HalfOpenCylinder object.
    cout << HalfOpenCylinder::CalculateSurfaceArea(5.0, 10.0);
    cout << "\n\n";

    // Here I am making an object of type CallFunctionAndMethodTester so that I can call
    // the method inside it that is using my example of how to call functions and methods
    // from within classes.
    CallFunctionAndMethodTester tester;
    cout << "Everything printed to the console after this line is printed using functions and methods that are called from inside classes. \n\n";
    tester.MethodInsideTheClass();

    int meh;
    cin >> meh;
    return 0;
}

/* Here is the output of this code when the program runs:

Cylinder 1 Values:
5
10
392.699

Cylinder 1 new surface area once Height is changed:
722.566

Cylinder 2 Values:
5
20.5
722.566

392.699

Everything printed to the console after this line is printed using functions and methods that are called from inside classes.

The below is printed from a function called in a class:
This is the text from the function named: ThisIsAFunction

The below is printed from a static method called in a class:
5261.38

The below is printed from an object's method called in a class:
1.5

*/
```

Comment: Try to avoid non-Standard, implementation-specific code in answers where the tool chain hasn't been specified. The odds of your example not working for them for a trivial reason that the asker does not understand is too high.

Comment: I meant for my answer to be more of a reference, or example, rather than something they could plug in to their own code and play with.  I even specify in the beginning of my answer that it is a stand alone piece of code that can be placed into a blank template to run.  To quote myself: "I went to new project, and created a "Win32 Console Application" in the C++ category.".  I understand Stack Overflow is more of a direct answer type site, but I figured this user just needed a few examples.  I'll try and avoid indirect examples in the future.

Comment: In my opinion it is just too much code and there's so much I can't even tell if it answers the question. It certainly doesn't in a direct way. There's no need for precompiled headers, so you should remove that. `__readonly` doesn't belong in a platform agnostic example. `using namespace std;` is a terrible habit you should not be teaching others. There's also an easily avoidable warning in this code.

Comment: Ah, sweet criticism.  This is why I joined Stack Overflow.  Thank you.  I appreciate the advice.